# In C++, when delete calls the destructor, does the body of the destructor trigger before memory is freed?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

For example, I'm trying to delete a binary tree using this recursive deconstructor:

```
~BinTreeNode() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
    // delete this; <- i'm assuming this is implicit, so i don't need to include it
}
```

If I do `delete root;` where root is the root node, will the memory for the entire tree be successfully freed?

Comment: assuming that the *only* memory used in the tree is `left` and `right`, where `left` and `right` are `BinTreeNode` pointers, then yes

Comment: your assumption re `delete this` being implicit is correct

Comment: Well, it's not implicit.  It's explicitly already been started.

Comment: In a word: _yes_. In fact, if you did say `delete this;`, that would cause recursion and would likely fail spectacularly.

Comment: in a few more words: yes, but you actually should be using std::unique_ptr if you unconditionally free left and right.

Comment: You could use unique_ptr even if you are conditionally deleting left and right.  unique_ptr will let go of its pointer without deleting if you ask it to.

Comment: `delete this` is complete nonsense, because the object has no control over how it was allocated. You must only say `delete` on the result of a `new` expression.

Comment: A class can indeed be in charge of how it's created.  Privatize the constructors and provide factory functions instead.  Then it can `delete this` in like a `destroy()` function or perhaps `decref()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  The body of the destructor HAS to happen before the memory is freed.  You don't need to delete this because you already are...so if you did then bad things would happen.